# The value of $a^i$.

Tags: complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

I recently tried to compute the value of $a^i$ and $a^{1/i}$ and found $a^i = \cos(\ln(a)) + i\sin(\ln(a))$ as
\begin{align}
a^i &= e^{\ln(a^i)} = e^{i\ln(a)}
\end{align}
and using Euler's Formula
\begin{align}
a^i = e^{i\ln(a)} = \cos(\ln(a))+ i\sin(\ln(a)).
\end{align}
Does this seem correct?

Comment: Note: $1/i=-i.$

Comment: That formula is fine when $a>0$ is real. Technically, $\ln (a)$ takes multiple values, so you can get multiple options, but for positive reals, we usually stick with the real logarithm.

Comment: How can ln(a) take multiple values (I am not familiar with this concept)?